# Is my internet traffic going through (3rd party) VPN in Windows10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, task-manager

When I use a third party VPN program in windows it should use all the bandwidth according to the task manager right? (Or at least should be the only one using any bandwidth)

But if another program appears in the task manager using bandwidth it means that the program isn't using the VPN connection?

Routing table:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  9...00 ff 33 e5 aa 46 ......Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter #2
  6...d8 cb 8a c6 cb 82 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
 16...00 ff d9 5a 0c bc ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      (ipv4   ).1     (ipv4   ).35     35
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0    10.102.37.149    10.102.37.150      1
       10.102.0.1  255.255.255.255    10.102.37.149    10.102.37.150      1
    10.102.37.148  255.255.255.252         On-link     10.102.37.150    257
    10.102.37.150  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.102.37.150    257
    10.102.37.151  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.102.37.150    257
    95.179.212.15  255.255.255.255      (ipv4   ).1     (ipv4   ).35     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0    10.102.37.149    10.102.37.150      1
      (ipv4   ).0    255.255.255.0         On-link      (ipv4   ).35    291
     (ipv4   ).35  255.255.255.255         On-link      (ipv4   ).35    291
    (ipv4   ).255  255.255.255.255         On-link      (ipv4   ).35    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      (ipv4   ).35    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.102.37.150    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      (ipv4   ).35    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.102.37.150    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  6     51 ::/0                     fe80::8626:15ff:feb0:f4d3
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  6     51 2001:8a0:d208:a501::/64  On-link
  6    291 2001:8a0:d208:a501:5bd:8a53:b1dd:234/128
                                    On-link
  6    291 2001:8a0:d208:a501:b457:b553:4ae5:22ff/128
                                    On-link
  6    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    291 fe80::23:298b:d208:758a/128
                                    On-link
  6    291 (ipv6address)/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: In fact, you would see “all bandwidth” twice: Once when it is funneled into the VPN client’s virtual network adapter. And then again when the VPN client itself sends it to the VPN server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All applications will still show up in Resource Monitor regardless of the path taken to reach the internet.

Every application is calling into the windows network service, even if you are using VPN, so every application still gets counted individually. When you use VPN, the path traffic takes after it is received by the windows network service is altered so that traffic is sent back into software (the VPN application), indirectly reaching the internet.

Comment: Nice, that answers to one of the questions, is there a way to check if all internet traffic is really going through the VPN?

Comment: Dump the windows routing table. The only IP addresses that should not be going to VPN is loopback, your LAN, and the IP of the VPN server itself. Run "ROUTE PRINT" from command prompt. Paste the results here if you are having difficulty understanding them.

Comment: I added the routing table to the question post since it was too big for a comment.
I had the VPN turned on (connected) when I did the "ROUTE PRINT" command

Comment: Your route info is correct.

What I needed to see was that the lowest metric (most prefered) route to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 is being routed to VPN (10.102.37.149). I actually don't see this; what I see instead is that 0.0.0.0/128.0.0.0 and 128.0.0.0/128.0.0.0 are being routed to vpn (10.102.37.149). These are more specific routes, so they supersede metric. This is common trick VPN applications use so they can 'beat' a metric of 1. The only other route of interest is 95.179.212.15/255.255.255.255, which is specifically allowing only the VPN server IP to route to the internet.

Comment: I think your ipv6 routes may actually be incorrect though. I don't know how to fix it. If you want to fix ipv6 so that it has to go though VPN, post it as another question with the ipv6 tag.

Comment: All in all the VPN is working, so the lowest metric is the most important, thanks!
As for the ipv6, this VPN does not support ipv6 so it simply disables it (at least I think it does, so far any "find my ip" website managed to guess my ipv6 address) (it doesn't support ipv6 for being a cheap VPN most likely).